# Edit table in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to delete/update a table on button event.

I have a table like this

```
  <table class="SimpleCalendar">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
        <th>Sun</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And I want to modify the inner HTML by clicking a button

```
$('.submit').click(function() 
{   
    var mytable = $('.SimpleCalendar');
    mytable.innerHTML = "test";
});
```

When I use firebug or the analysis button of my browser I can see that the innerHTML is changed but it display the same table over and over on my webpage.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Setting the `innerHTML` of a table to simply `test` is going to generate some invalid HTML. Also, a jQuery object doesn't have a `innerHTML` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.SimpleCalendar')` returns a jQuery collection. `innerHTML` is a property of the `HTMLElement` objects. Defining a `innerHTML` property on a jQuery collection effectively doesn't do anything. You should either get the jQuery wrapped element from the collection using [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method and then reset the `innerHTML` property or use the jQuery [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method instead.